# Flutter Flexible not wrapping text within a column

Tags: flutter, word-wrap

I am trying to make a widget that may have some long text that I would want to wrap a few lines.

I am trying to use the "[`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)" widget to wrap my `Text` but it is still overflowing and I do not know what is going wrong.

Here is what is happening: [image]

Here is my code for the `Column`s which will be relevant to the `Text`:

```
Container(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        'My Title text',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Colors.black),
      ),
      Text(
        'This is lower text',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
            fontSize: 16.0,
            color: Colors.black),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: Text(
          'Here is some long text that I am expecting will go off of the screen.',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              fontSize: 16.0,
              color: Colors.black),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

And in case it is relevant, here is the whole widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Container(
          height: 100.0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.cake,
                    size: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'My Title text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'This is lower text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Here is some long text that I am expecting will go off of the screen.',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I think parent widget of flexible is not enough space to expand. Try to set height for Container, if it work, try to fix it

Comment: @hoangquyy I just tried that and it did not work to wrap it.

Comment: Set for 2 Container, the above one and the bottom. Futhermore, I suggest you to use Expanded with flex in Row or Collumn widget, it make your app more flexible.

Comment: @thalacker for this view you can use the widget ListTile without any issue like above. This is easy to use and made for this type of use cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Expanded Here. **Expanded**, which forces the child to expand to fill the available space. you can expand column here.

**Here is code snippet for column:-**

```
Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'My Title text',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'This is lower text',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            'Here is some long text that I am expecting will go off of the screen.',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

**Here is what you expect:-**
[image]

Hope it will work.

Comment: OMG. 5 hours trying to fix this, and this works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the Container to Expanded inside Row widget
Like this

```dart
child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.cake,
                    size: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'My Title text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'This is lower text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Here is some long text that I am expecting will go off of the screen.',
                          softWrap: true,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
             ) ],
            ),
```

The problem is if you didn't put the Container into Expanded, the Row widget keeps expand itself to horizontal and it would overflow.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this approach by placing the `width` of the container to 70% and for an image 30%. There is no need for Flexible widget over here

```
Container(
 width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        'Here is some long text that I am expecting will go off of the screen.',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Colors.black),
      ),
      Text(
        'Here is some long text that I am expecting will go off of the screen.',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
            fontSize: 16.0,
            color: Colors.black),
      ),
      Text(
          'Here is some long text that I am expecting will go off of the screen.',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              fontSize: 16.0,
              color: Colors.black
         )
    ],
  ),
),
```